# How to prevent my textbox from clearing text on postback.

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, textbox, postback

I have a pretty interesting dilemma that is giving me a hurricane of a headache. I've seen a similar question asked here, but the user posted no code, so it was unresolved. This is a asp.net, sql server, and c# app.

In my application, I use JavaScript to display dummy data in a `TextBox` to entertain the user while a long process is running. (please note, this is a project, not a professional app).

The problem is, once the app is done executing, the app (I believe) refreshes the page and clears the `TextBox`. I want to prevent this from happening and continue to display the text after the program is completed.

My question is, where in the following code is the page being refreshed? How can I re-code it to prevent the text from being cleared?

I know there is no issue with the JavaScript or the .aspx page. I have not set or programmed any property to clear the text. If anyone could shed light on the issue, I would greatly appreciate it. If you need more code from me please let me know. I will be very active on this page until it is resolved. Thanks again!

```
public partial class SendOrders : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected enum EDIType
    {
        Notes,
        Details
    }

    protected static string NextBatchNum = "1";
    protected static string FileNamePrefix = "";
    protected static string OverBatchLimitStr = "Batch file limit has been reached.  No more batches can be processed today.";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }

    protected void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
    }

    protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PutFTPButton.Enabled = false;
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        KaplanFTP.BatchFiles bf = new KaplanFTP.BatchFiles();
        KaplanFTP.Transmit transmit = new KaplanFTP.Transmit();

        if (btn.ID == PutFTPButton.ID)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Kaplan");
            FileInfo[] BatchFiles = bf.GetBatchFiles(dir);
            bool result = transmit.UploadBatchFilesToFTP(BatchFiles);

            if (!result)
            {
                ErrorLabel.Text += KaplanFTP.errorMsg;
                return;
            }

            bf.InsertBatchDataIntoDatabase("CTL");
            bf.InsertBatchDataIntoDatabase("HDR");
            bf.InsertBatchDataIntoDatabase("DET");
            bf.InsertBatchDataIntoDatabase("NTS");

            List<FileInfo> allfiles = BatchFiles.ToList<FileInfo>();
            allfiles.AddRange(dir.GetFiles("*.txt"));
            bf.MoveFiles(allfiles);

            foreach (string order in bf.OrdersSent)
            {
                OrdersSentDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(order + "<br />"));
            }

            btnExit.Visible = true;
            OrdersSentDiv.Visible = true;
            OrdersInfoDiv.Visible = false;
            SuccessLabel.Visible = true;
            NoBatchesToProcessLbl.Visible = true;
            BatchesToProcessLbl.Visible = false;
            PutFTPButton.Enabled = false;
            BatchesCreatedLbl.Text = int.Parse(NextBatchNum).ToString();
            Thread.Sleep(20000);

            if (KaplanFTP.errorMsg.Length != 0)
            {
                ErrorLabel.Visible = false;
                SuccessLabel.Visible = true;
                ErrorLabel.Text = KaplanFTP.errorMsg;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
          KaplanFTP.BatchFiles bf = new KaplanFTP.BatchFiles();

          if (!IsPostBack)
          {
              FileNamePrefix = bf.FileNamePrefix;
              NextBatchNum = bf.NextBatchNum;
              BatchesCreatedLbl.Text = (int.Parse(NextBatchNum) - 1).ToString();

              if (bf.CheckLocalForNewBatch() == true)
              {
                  NoBatchesToProcessLbl.Visible = false;
                  BatchesToProcessLbl.Visible = true;
                  if (int.Parse(NextBatchNum) >= 50)
                  {
                      ErrorLabel.Text += ErrorLabel.Text + OverBatchLimitStr;
                      ErrorLabel.Visible = true;
                      PutFTPButton.Enabled = false;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      bf.ReadyFilesForTransmission();
                      ErrorLabel.Visible = false;
                      PutFTPButton.Enabled = true;
                      List<string[]> detStream = bf.GetBatchStream("DET");
                      List<string[]> hdrStream = bf.GetBatchStream("HDR");
                      OrdersInfoDiv.Visible = true;

                      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                      dt.Columns.Add("ORDER NUMBER");
                      dt.Columns.Add("LINE NUMBER");
                      dt.Columns.Add("ITEM NUMBER/ISBN");
                      dt.Columns.Add("DESCRIPTION");
                      dt.Columns.Add("QUANTITY");
                      dt.Columns.Add("SHIPPING");

                      Dictionary<string, string> orderShip = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                      foreach (string[] hdrItems in hdrStream)
                      {
                          orderShip.Add(hdrItems[0], hdrItems[2]);
                      }
                      foreach (string[] detItems in detStream)
                      {
                          List<string> detLineList = new List<string>(detItems);
                          detLineList.Add(orderShip[detItems[0]]);
                          detLineList.RemoveAt(13);
                          detLineList.RemoveAt(12);
                          detLineList.RemoveAt(11);
                          detLineList.RemoveAt(10);
                          detLineList.RemoveAt(9);
                          detLineList.RemoveAt(8);
                          detLineList.RemoveAt(7);
                          detLineList.RemoveAt(4);
                          detLineList.RemoveAt(2);
                          detLineList[1] = detLineList[1].TrimStart('0');
                          detLineList[4] = detLineList[4].TrimStart('0');
                          dt.Rows.Add(detLineList.ToArray());
                      }

                      BatchDetails.DataSource = dt;
                      BatchDetails.DataBind();
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  NoBatchesToProcessLbl.Visible = true;
                  BatchesToProcessLbl.Visible = false;
                  PutFTPButton.Enabled = false;
              }
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: I used code behind. But all the javascript does in insert the text in the text box and thats it. Would you like me post that code as well?

Comment: Is the textbox in question referenced in this code at all? Are you using UpdatePanels?

Comment: The textbox is only referenced on javascript and html pages. Im not using update panels. The textbox on the page which is the code posted above. The issue is the refresh/postback which is on this page and not the actual js or html dealing with the textbox

Comment: As a piece of advice, you **really** need to break this code out. This is a spaghetti-code nightmare in its present state. You would be well-served by writing classes that handle the details of the batch file processing and the data tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You will have to determine the state of your calculation and populate the control inside Page_Load in the case where IsPostBack is true:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   if (IsPostBack) {
      // re-populate javascript-fill UI
   } else {
   } 
   Initialize();
}
```

You can probably also move Initialize() into the else clause as well.

Comment: Hmmm this is a good idea. How would you write this in javascript?

Comment: You don't write this is javascript. This has to be in your c# code behind to persist the data through postbacks.

Comment: ahha i understand. you sir are a f*&king genius. Thanks alot!

Comment: Thank you for the complement. It comes from many, many pages of c#.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are handling the button click server side (I'm assuming the problem is happening once the user clicks the button?) there has to be a postback to handle it.

You could try putting your button and label into an `updatepanel` control - it uses AJAX to refresh its contents.

See [this page](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) for more information on `updatepanel`s.